# Custom UITableViewCell with UITextView inside is not editable with layoutsubviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextview

I created a custom `UITableViewCell` with .xib and .h and .m files, and I added a `UITextView` to the cell, and I implemented the `-layoutSubviews` method. But with this method I can't write text in the `UITextView`, instead without it I can, this is the code in the .m file:

MyCell.m

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [self.comment_text setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [self.comment_text setEditable:YES];
    //I need this method to hide some view on touch...
}
```

instead if I do this:

```
/*
    - (void)layoutSubviews
    {
        [self.comment_text setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        [self.comment_text setEditable:YES];
        //I need this method to hide some view on touch...
    }
*/
```

so when I remove it, I can edit text in `UITextView`. Why? How can I fix it?

Comment: try calling `[super layoutSubviews]` at the beginning of the method

Comment: Anytime! Accept the answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `[super layoutSubviews]` in your overriding method.

Try this:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    [self.comment_text setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [self.comment_text setEditable:YES];
}
```